# Orthogonal Projection onto a Sub-space

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Can anyone help? I am really stuck on this question.

Find the orthogonal projection of $(49  \ \
49 \ \
49 )^T$ on to the subspace $V$ of  $R^3$ spanned by $(2 \ \
3 \ \
6)^T$ and $(3 \
-6 \ \
  2)^T $

(Sorry I don't know how to format matrices into the question. They are just meant to be stacked $3 \times 1  \ $ matrices.)

Comment: What question??

Comment: sorry i just edited the post @coffeemath

Answer (score 1):

First you can get a vector orthogonal to that plane by forming the cross product $n$ of $(2,3,6)$ and $(3,-6,2).$ Next, if you form $P(k)=-(49,49,49)+kn,$ that vector starts at $(49,49,49)$ and is orthogonal to the plane. Only thing left now is to find what $k$ value makes $P(k)$ end up on the plane, plug in. I'll leave the last part for you...  Note I changed the sign on $P(k)$ [which makes no real difference, but makes it as a vector start at $(49,49,49)$]

Comment: sorry i am very new at this but would the cross product be (42, 14, -21)?

Comment: @s.sey That is the correct cross product. Keep  me posted via comments about how you do on the rest of the steps.